# Disabling Istio/Zipkin interceptor for a single request?

Tags: jms, istio, zipkin

We are using Istio/Zipkin as a tracing system on our server to add the dynamic headers through Istio sidecar proxy for tracing the request later on using Zipkin. Is there anyway we could disable istio for a certain request. 
Problem is, we are working with JMS queues, and when JMS listener tries to listen to a certain queue, it sees the headers like x-request-id added by the istio dynamically and it gives an error (as it'll accept header keys only in camelCase or with underScore or $). We can change header keys added by istio, so we want either istio to not to add headers in some specific requests (the one queue is making). 
I've searched google but couldn't find anything about it.

Following is the error message we are getting:

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue' - trying to recover. 
Cause: Identifier contains invalid JMS identifier character '-': 'x-request-id'
```

Comment: @JustinBertram This question was asked by me yesterday. That is related to renaming istio's headers whilst here I'm interested to know if we could add exception for a single request in istio to avoid headers being added by istio in our request. 
By the way, that question doesn't have any answer either.

Comment: That previous comment (which I have now deleted) was added automatically when I voted to close this question. I realize that both this question and the other were asked by you and that the other one doesn't have an answer yet. However, the underlying problem is the same in both - the `JMSListener` is choking on non-JMS-compliant header names from Istio. Each question is asking if a specific solution to the same problem is possible. Instead you should have a single question describing the problem and asking for **any** solution.